# Добавить ssl сертификат к Electron

Tags: linux, node.js, centos, ssl, electron

Для работы с серверами заказчика нужен ssl, сделали свой CA и сгенерировали тестовый сертификат, расширение *.crt, передали копии им, приватные ключи у нас, наc авторизовали как доверенных, тестовый запрос через cUrl отработал нормально, пример запроса:

`curl -vvvv --cert ./ИМЯ_СЕРТИФИКАТА.crt --key ./ИМЯ_КЛЮЧА.key --header -X POST
"https://XXXXXXX.XXX:XXXX/XXXXX/XXXX" --data 'ID=XXXXXXXXXXX&GAME=XXXX&DRAW=XX'`

В общем, суть проблемы: У нас приложение на Electron, как прикрутить сертификаты к приложению в режиме разработки и в собранном виде, просто закидывать в локальное хранилище сертификатов или необходимы другие манипуляции ещё с Electron?